# Creating a User Profile with UICollectionView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, storyboard, uicollectionview

At the moment I am trying to create a user profile view on top of a `UICollectionView`. Much like this example, except the bottom part (after the profile image), would be a grid of images (much like Instagram). Also, the entire page should scroll together.

User Profile Header:
[image: User Profile Header]

I'm relatively new to iOS development and I'm not sure what would be the best approach to achieve this view. I've tried to embed a `UIView` to the top of `UICollectionView` using Storyboard, but that doesn't seem to be working. Is there a way to do this programmatically? Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: It looks like they are using a UITableView not UICollectionView. UITableView has a tableHeaderView property that will display an arbitrary UIView at the top (i.e. before section 0's header view) that will scroll with its rows.

Comment: Maybe this is a better example? [this](https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/3347/screenshots/2358138/attached-dribbble.jpg) or [this](https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/354716/screenshots/2406695/experticity---live-in-the-app-store.jpg), both of these would require me to use a CollectionView right?

Comment: You should use custom cells for every different section, at least one for header with profile data and another for the other cells. When implementing UICollectionView/UITableView delegate you should manage wich one to show depending on wich row you are.

Comment: You can use Decoration Views or Supplementary Views to achieve the same thing with a UICollectionView

Comment: did you found any better solution?